# How can I tell a Microsoft-hosted agent in Azure Devops to preserve the workspace between jobs?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore, azure-devops-hosted-agent

I want to break down a large job, running on a Microsoft-hosted agent, into smaller jobs running sequentially, on the same agent. The large job is organized like this:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

jobs:
- job: large_job
  steps:
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
       inputs:
          command: 'restore'
    - task: VSBuild@1
    - task: VSTest@2
```

I want to break it down into two smaller jobs, like this:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

jobs:
- job: job_one
  steps:
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
       inputs:
          command: 'restore'

- job: job_two
  dependsOn: job_one
  steps:
    - checkout: none
    - task: VSBuild@1
    - task: VSTest@2
```

... so that downloading all of my binary resources will happen in `job_one`, and the build and test will happen in `job_two`.

Jobs include an optional parameter, `workspace:clean`, which is used with self-hosted agents to specify whether the binary resources, build results, or everything should be erased from the agent. If the `workspace:clean` parameter is omitted, nothing is erased -- everything is preserved. That's what I want.

However, according to the [Workspace topic in the Azure Devops documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#workspace):

> The workspace clean options are applicable only for self-hosted agents. When using Microsoft-hosted agents, jobs are always run on a new agent.

This means that all of my binary resources are erased before `job_two` can run the build task. I want to do the equivalent of this:

```
- job: job_two
  dependsOn: job_one
  workspace:
    clean: none
  steps:
    - checkout: none
    - task: VSBuild@1
    - task: VSTest@2
```

I want to avoid using a self-hosted agent. How can I do this using a Microsoft-hosted agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't ever rely on the workspace being the same between jobs, *period* -- jobs may run on any one of the available agents, which are spread across multiple working folders and possibly even on different physical machines.

Have your jobs [publish artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

i.e.

```
steps:
- publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/bin/WebApp
  artifact: WebApp
```

And then in down-stream jobs,

```
steps:
- download: current
  artifact: WebApp
```

However, what you're really looking for appears to be using a [pipeline cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops) for your packages.

Comment: Both solutions worked. I'm going to use the pipeline cache.